# SP_SEND_DBMAIL @QUERY Inserts Line Breaks Into E-mail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I use the @query perimeter in sp_send_dbmail to send out an e-mail with a list of warnings (the warnings are returned by the @query perimeter).  The @query perimeter is listed as text in the e-mail.  All of the records returned from the @query perimeter and displayed in the e-mail has a line break between them.  ie. If I have 4 records, I would have 8 lines because of line breaks.

How do I turn the line breaks off?  I read the the msdn article for sp_send_dbmail, but it didn't mention any attributes that could be changed that would affect the line breaks.

Code:

```
    BEGIN
    EXEC MSDB.DBO.sp_send_dbmail 
        @PROFILE_NAME = 'Alerts',
        @RECIPIENTS = @MAIL,
        @SUBJECT = @NEWSUBJECT,
        @BODY = @NEWBODY,
        @QUERY =
            'SET NOCOUNT ON
            DECLARE @HEXSTRING AS VARCHAR(100)
            SET @HEXSTRING = (SELECT HEXADECIMAL_STRING FROM mydb.dbo.statusupdates
                WHERE MACHINE_ID = ''1111'' AND DATEDIFF(MI, TIME_DATE_RECEIVED, GETDATE()) <= 60)
            SELECT [Warning_Description] FROM mydb.DBO.BINARYTOTABLE(mydb.DBO.HEXTOBINARY(@HEXSTRING)) AS ABB1
            JOIN mydb.DBO.WarningMessages  ON mydb.DBO.WarningMessages.[Bit_Offset] = ABB1.BITPLACE
            WHERE BITVALUE = 1 AND ALERT_LEVEL = ''WARNING''',
        @QUERY_RESULT_HEADER = 0,
        @ATTACH_QUERY_RESULT_AS_FILE = 0;
    END
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your code?  Including all parameters for sp_send_dbmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting everything into the @BODY parameter of SP_SEND_DBMAIL.  Query results from a SELECT statement could be concatenated with regular text into a string and you can use HTML to format the resulting text.

Answer (score 5):

Old post, but probably worth checking @query_result_width parameter of sp_send_dbmail

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307(v=sql.110).aspx

If the data width in a column  exceeds @query_result_width (default of 256) a new line will be added.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

I have always used CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) to create line breaks in tsql. You will have to replace it by ' '.

Answer (score 0):

try this and see what you get ...

```
 @query = REPLACE(@query,CHR(13),'')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use the above code inside of MSDB.DBO.sp_send_dbmail

Comment: that is why you should create another variable where you can perform the replace function and then set @query = SomeOtherVariable in the parameters of the proc